# Convert from eastings and northings to latitude and longitude without ArcGIS

Tags: shapefile, r, matlab, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I am not a GIS user, but I was given some shapefiles to work with. I do not have ArcGIS or any other GIS tool, but I do have Matlab with the mapping toolbox and R.

From what I can tell, the data is in eastings/northings in meters relative to some reference point.  According to the metadata, the projection is WGS_1984_Mercator.  There is another parameter that lists GCS_WGS_1984.  I need to convert this into latitude and longitude relative to zero latitude and longitude.  I do not need very high accuracy - within a degree or two is fine.

Here's some additional info, though I'm not totally sure that it's all relevant:

```
dbfdata: {[1]  [7.5947e-05]  [0.9000]}
dfbdate: [2012 7 2]
SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]]
PROJECTION['Mercator'],
PARAMETER['False_Easting',0.0],
PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0]
```

My apologies if I haven't provided enough information - please let me know what else I need to provide.

Comment: @whuber usually I trust you, but this does look like a projected coordinate system (maybe the post has been edited since your comment).

Comment: @rdouxju It doesn't look edited, but now I clearly see the Mercator projection indicated!  I apologize for having been misleading and I'll delete that comment.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Does the shapefile come with a .prj file (along with the .shp, .shx and .dbf)? That should definitively define the projection. Also, why not give QGIS a try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your projection is likely to be the [World Mercator](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3395/) projection. (EPSG 3395)

You can use the package [proj4](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/proj4/project.html) in R to transform your coordinates. It is also supported by Matlab (as you can see [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/map/mercatorprojection.html?searchHighlight=mercator%20projection)).

projection = +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

inverse=true to go from cartographic coordinates to geographic coordinates (Lat/long)